# Time complexity of finding the smallest value in an unordered array

Tags: algorithm

I was reading the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Constant_time) which says:

> However, finding the minimal value in an unordered array is not a
>   constant time operation as scanning over each element in the array is
>   needed in order to determine the minimal value. Hence it is a linear
>   time operation, taking O(n) time. If the number of elements is known
>   in advance and does not change, however, such an algorithm can still
>   be said to run in constant time.

I am not able to understand how the time complexity becomes constant if the number of elements is known in advance? Will it still not be O(n)?

Comment: If the number of elements is known in advance and doesn't change, then it is *constant*.  In that case there simply is no variable `n` for the algorithm to be `O(n)`.

Comment: @JohnColeman, can you explain it with an example?

Comment: Say that there are `100` elements in the array. Then you have to look at `100` elements, and `100` is a constant multiple of `1`, so: `O(1)`. Also, big-O notation is for what happens *asymptotically* as `n` tends to infinity. Constants stay fixed rather than tending to infinity, so asymptotic questions really don't even arise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the definition of Big-O:

> f(n) = O(g(n)) means there are positive constants c and k, such that 0 ≤ f(n) ≤ cg(n) for all n ≥ k. The values of c and k must be fixed for the function f and must not depend on n.

If we know the array size, say 100, it is clear that 100 steps will take us to check what is the minimal value in the array.

Therefore, for every n ≥ 1, c = 100:

100 ≤ 1 * 100

Which means (by the definition):

100 = O(1)

So the time complexity becomes O(1).

If you still cannot understand, try proving it for n-sized array.